# Dictionary lookup throws "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, dictionary

I received an error report which seems to come from the following code:

```
public class AnimationChannelCollection : ReadOnlyCollection<BoneKeyFrameCollection>
{
        private Dictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection> dict =
            new Dictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection>();

        private ReadOnlyCollection<string> affectedBones;

       // This immutable data structure should not be created by the library user
        internal AnimationChannelCollection(IList<BoneKeyFrameCollection> channels)
            : base(channels)
        {
            // Find the affected bones
            List<string> affected = new List<string>();
            foreach (BoneKeyFrameCollection frames in channels)
            {
                dict.Add(frames.BoneName, frames);
                affected.Add(frames.BoneName);
            }
            affectedBones = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(affected);

        }

        public BoneKeyFrameCollection this[string boneName]
        {           
            get { return dict[boneName]; }
        }
}
```

---

This is the calling code that reads the dictionary:

```
public override Matrix GetCurrentBoneTransform(BonePose pose)
    {
        BoneKeyFrameCollection channel =  base.AnimationInfo.AnimationChannels[pose.Name];       
    }
```

---

This is the code that creates the dictionary, happens on startup:

```
// Reads in processed animation info written in the pipeline
internal sealed class AnimationReader :   ContentTypeReader<AnimationInfoCollection>
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Reads in an XNB stream and converts it to a ModelInfo object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The stream from which the data will be read</param>
    /// <param name="existingInstance">Not used</param>
    /// <returns>The unserialized ModelAnimationCollection object</returns>
    protected override AnimationInfoCollection Read(ContentReader input, AnimationInfoCollection existingInstance)
    {
        AnimationInfoCollection dict = new AnimationInfoCollection();
        int numAnimations = input.ReadInt32();

        /* abbreviated */

        AnimationInfo anim = new AnimationInfo(animationName, new AnimationChannelCollection(animList));

    }
}
```

The error is:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> Line: 0
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>
> at
>   Xclna.Xna.Animation.InterpolationController.GetCurrentBoneTransform(BonePose
>   pose)

I would have expected a KeyNotFoundException with the wrong key, but instead I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array".
I don't understand how I could get that exception from the above code?

The code is singlethreaded by the way.

Comment: The code doesn't compile.  Surely you meant `return dict[boneName];`

Comment: Where's the return for the getter?

Comment: In addition, once adding the proper return, I correctly receive `KeyNotFoundException`.  You need to update your code to properly reproduce the issue as it currently does not.

Answer (score 38):

A *"Index was outside the bounds of the array."* error on a Dictionary (or anything in the `System.Collections` namespace) when the documentation says the error should not be thrown is ***always*** caused by you violating thread safety.

All collections in the `System.Collections` namespace allow only one of two operations happen

- Unlimited concurrent readers, 0 writers.
- 0 readers, 1 writer.

You either must synchronize all access to the dictionary using a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) which gives the exact behavior described above

```
private Dictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection> dict =
            new Dictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection>();
private ReaderWriterLockSlim dictLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public BoneKeyFrameCollection this[string boneName]
{           
    get 
    { 
        try
        {
            dictLock.EnterReadLock();
            return dict[boneName]; 
        }
        finally
        {
            dictLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}


 public void UpdateBone(string boneName, BoneKeyFrameCollection col)
 {  
    try
    {
        dictLock.EnterWriteLock();
        dict[boneName] = col; 
    }
    finally
    {
        dictLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
 }
```

or replace your `Dictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection>` with a [`ConcurrentDictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection> dict =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, BoneKeyFrameCollection>();

 public BoneKeyFrameCollection this[string boneName]
 {           
    get 
    { 
        return dict[boneName];
    }
 }

 public void UpdateBone(string boneName, BoneKeyFrameCollection col)
 {  
    dict[boneName] = col;
 }
```

---

**UPDATE:** I really don't see how the code you have shown could have caused this. [Here is the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) for the function that is causing it to be thrown.

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
    if( key == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }

    if (buckets != null) {
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The only way that code throws a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is if you try to index a illegal record in `buckets` or `entries`.

Because your key is a `string` and strings are immutable we can rule out a `hashcode` value for a key that was changed after the key was put in to the dictionary. All that remains is a `buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]` call and a few `entries[i]` calls.

The only way `buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]` could fail is if the instance of `buckets` was replaced between the `buckets.Length` property call and the `this[int index]` indexer call. The only time `buckets` gets replaced is when [`Resize`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,3b9a0882313262cd,) is called internally by [`Insert`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9), `Initialize` is called by the constructor/first call to `Insert`, or on a call to `OnDeserialization`.

The only places `Insert` gets called is the setter for `this[TKey key]`, the public `Add` function, and inside `OnDeserialization`. The only way for `buckets` to be replaced is if we are making calls to one of the three listed functions at the same moment the `FindEntry` call happens on the other thread during the `buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]` call.

The only way we could get a bad `entries[i]` call is if `entries` gets swapped out on us (follows the same rules as `buckets`) or we get a bad value for `i`. The only way to get a bad value for `i` is if `entries[i].next` returns a bad value. The only way to get a bad value from `entries[i].next` is to have  concurrent operations going on during `Insert`, `Resize`, or `Remove`.

The only thing I can think of is either something is going wrong on a `OnDeserialization` call and you have bad data to start with before deserialization or there is more code to `AnimationChannelCollection` that affects the dictionary that you are not showing us.

Comment: That's great. But the code is singlethreaded I believe... but at least I can rule out missing keys as the source of the error.

Comment: The animations are loaded into the readonly collection at start. But the error occurred well into a game session during a normal frame Update. The collection is not modified after the game has loaded. So I don't see where the writer should come from that would cause the exception.

Comment: Show how the initial loading is done as a edit to the question. The problem is there most likely. I have ***never*** seen this issue be anything other than "I used multiple concurrent writers on a collection" as the root cause.

Comment: @user1919998 the only other thing it could *maybe* be would be if the key you are using changed it's own `HashCode()` or `.Equals()` behavior while it was sitting in the key of the collection. But being that your key is a `string` I find it extreemly unlikely unless you did some weird non standard `IEqualityComparer<string>` when you created the dictionary.

Comment: I added the code showing how the dictionary is written to in the constructor only.

Comment: @user1919998 I added a big edit to my post showing my thought process. It has to be bad data on a `OnDeserialization` call or you have other stuff accessing the dictionary you are not showing us.

Comment: Wow! how do you even know things like that? I was struggling with my code for an entire day!

Comment: I've seen this error recently on a machine where IIS app pool was hitting 2Gb, could this be caused by being out of memory?

Comment: No, a different out of memory exception would happen.